# NUTCH 1.13 fetch of url failed with: org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolNotFound: protocol not found for url=http

Tags: solr, centos, nutch

> fetch of httpurl failed with:
>   org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolNotFound: protocol not found for
>   url=http  at
>   org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolFactory.getProtocol(ProtocolFactory.java:85)
>     at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:285)
>
> Using queue mode : byHost
>   fetch of httpsurl failed with: org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolNotFound: protocol not found for url=https
>       at org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolFactory.getProtocol(ProtocolFactory.java:85)
>       at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:285)

I get above result while running nutch1.13 with solr6.6.0

command i used is

> bin/crawl -i -D
>   solr.server.url=http://myip/solr/nutch/ urls/ crawl  2

below is plugin section in my nutch-site.xml

```
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>
protocol-(http|httpclient)|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)
</value>
```

Below are my file contents

```
    [root@localhost apache-nutch-1.13]# ls plugins
creativecommons      index-more           nutch-extensionpoints   protocol-file                 scoring-similarity         urlnormalizer-ajax
feed                 index-replace        parse-ext               protocol-ftp                  subcollection              urlnormalizer-basic
headings             index-static         parsefilter-naivebayes  protocol-htmlunit             tld                        urlnormalizer-host
index-anchor         language-identifier  parsefilter-regex       protocol-http                 urlfilter-automaton        urlnormalizer-pass
index-basic          lib-htmlunit         parse-html              protocol-httpclient           urlfilter-domain           urlnormalizer-protocol
indexer-cloudsearch  lib-http             parse-js                protocol-interactiveselenium  urlfilter-domainblacklist  urlnormalizer-querystring
indexer-dummy        lib-nekohtml         parse-metatags          protocol-selenium             urlfilter-ignoreexempt     urlnormalizer-regex
indexer-elastic      lib-regex-filter     parse-replace           publish-rabbitmq              urlfilter-prefix           urlnormalizer-slash
indexer-solr         lib-selenium         parse-swf               publish-rabitmq               urlfilter-regex
index-geoip          lib-xml              parse-tika              scoring-depth                 urlfilter-suffix
index-links          microformats-reltag  parse-zip               scoring-link                  urlfilter-validator
index-metadata       mimetype-filter      plugin                  scoring-opic                  urlmeta
```

I'm stuck with this issue. As you can see i have included both protocol-(http|httpclient) .But still fetching url failed.  Thanks in advance.

NEWER ISSUE hadoop.log

> 2017-09-01 14:35:07,172 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - SolrIndexer:
>   deleting 1/1 documents 2017-09-01 14:35:07,321 WARN 
>   output.FileOutputCommitter - Output Path is null in cleanupJob()
>   2017-09-01 14:35:07,323 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner -
>   job_local1176811933_0001 java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
>     at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)  at
>   org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:481)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.commit(SolrClient.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.commit(SolrClient.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.commit(SolrIndexWriter.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:179)
>     at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob$DeleterReducer.close(CleaningJob.java:122)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2017-09-01 14:35:07,679
>   ERROR indexer.CleaningJob - CleaningJob: java.io.IOException: Job
>   failed!   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.delete(CleaningJob.java:174)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.run(CleaningJob.java:197)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.main(CleaningJob.java:208)

Comment: Did you try to fetch it just with protocol-http?

Comment: yes. still that fetching failed. do i have to include plugin somewhere else

Comment: could you paste the output of: bin/nutch parsechecker http://your_url

Comment: [root@localhost apache-nutch-1.13]# bin/nutch parsechecker http://183.134.100.180:8983/solr/nutch/
fetching: http://183.134.100.180:8983/solr/nutch/
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolNotFound: protocol not found for url=http
 at org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolFactory.getProtocol(ProtocolFactory.java:85)
 at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker.run(ParserChecker.java:136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker.main(ParserChecker.java:267)

Comment: [root@localhost apache-nutch-1.13]# bin/nutch parsechecker https://www.theguardian.com/media/bbc
fetching: https://www.theguardian.com/media/bbc
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolNotFound: protocol not found for url=https
 at org.apache.nutch.protocol.ProtocolFactory.getProtocol(ProtocolFactory.java:85)
 at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker.run(ParserChecker.java:136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker.main(ParserChecker.java:267)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow solved the issue. I think the space in  nutch-site.xml was causing issue new plugin.includes section for others coming here.

```
      <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
```

Comment: I ran into a new problem
[root@localhost apache-nutch-1.13]# bin/nutch clean crawl/crawldb/ http://183.134.100.180:8983/solr/nutch/
SolrIndexer: deleting 1/1 documents
SolrIndexer: deleting 1/1 documents
ERROR CleaningJob: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
 at org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.delete(CleaningJob.java:174)
 at org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.run(CleaningJob.java:197)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.main(CleaningJob.java:208)

Comment: is this trace from hadoop.log?

Comment: hadoop trace is given as question edit since error is too long.. above is the command I ran on terminal with error returned there